# Issues with JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

Chrome keeps telling me that my syntax is wrong for JSON and I'm not understanding why. I want an array of "games" and each object within to be a different game, all values are hard-coded within the JSON file. It says my first object is fine, but as soon as it gets to the second objects opening curly bracket it tells me that the syntax is incorrect. I followed an example that I had previously found on this site and it was verified so not sure why mine is bombing out.

```
var games = [
    {
        "title" : "Mass Effect",
        "genre" : "Third-Person Shooter",
        "date" : "March 6, 2012",
        "character" : "Shepard",
        "weapon" : [
            {
             "Pistol" : "Kessler",
             "Assault Rifle" : "Lancer",
             "Shotgun" : "Sokolov",
             "Sniper Rifle" : "Titan"
            }
        ],  
    }
    { //this bracket here is where it is telling me my syntax is wrong
        "title" : "Resident Evil",
        "genre" : "Survival Horror",
        "date" : "March 22, 1996",
        "character" : "Chris Redfield",
        "weapon" : [
            {
             "Handgun" : "Nine-Oh-Nine",
             "Assault Rifle" : "Bear Commander",
             "Shotgun" : "Triple Shot",
             "Rifle" : "Anti-Matter Rifle"
            }
        ],
    }
    {
        "title" : "Halo",
        "genre" : "First-Person Shooter",
        "date" : "November 15, 2001",
        "character" : " Master Chief",
        "weapon" : [
            {
             "Pistol" : "M6D Personal Defense Weapon",
             "Assault Rifle" : "MA5B Individual Combat Weapon",
             "Shotgun" : "Oathsworn",
             "Rifle" : "BR85 Heavy Barrel Service Rifle"
            }
        ],
    }
    {
        "title" : "Final Fantasy 7",
        "genre" : "Role-Playing Game",
        "date" : "January 31, 1997",
        "character" : "Cloud Strife",
        "weapon" :  [
            {
             "Two-Handed Sword" : "Buster Sword",
             "Katana" : "Murasame",
             "Blunt Weapon" : "Nail Bar",
             "Ultimate Weapon" : "Ultima Weapon"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the actual error? Nevermind, there is a comma missing! Put `,` between the brackets

Comment: you're missing the commas between games - as in - " },
{ //this bracket here" - see that comma is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

Each should separate by **comma**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Mass Effect",
        "genre": "Third-Person Shooter",
        "date": "March 6, 2012",
        "character": "Shepard",
        "weapon": [
            {
                "Pistol": "Kessler",
                "Assault Rifle": "Lancer",
                "Shotgun": "Sokolov",
                "Sniper Rifle": "Titan"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Resident Evil",
        "genre": "Survival Horror",
        "date": "March 22, 1996",
        "character": "Chris Redfield",
        "weapon": [
            {
                "Handgun": "Nine-Oh-Nine",
                "Assault Rifle": "Bear Commander",
                "Shotgun": "Triple Shot",
                "Rifle": "Anti-Matter Rifle"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Halo",
        "genre": "First-Person Shooter",
        "date": "November 15, 2001",
        "character": " Master Chief",
        "weapon": [
            {
                "Pistol": "M6D Personal Defense Weapon",
                "Assault Rifle": "MA5B Individual Combat Weapon",
                "Shotgun": "Oathsworn",
                "Rifle": "BR85 Heavy Barrel Service Rifle"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Final Fantasy 7",
        "genre": "Role-Playing Game",
        "date": "January 31, 1997",
        "character": "Cloud Strife",
        "weapon": [
            {
                "Two-Handed Sword": "Buster Sword",
                "Katana": "Murasame",
                "Blunt Weapon": "Nail Bar",
                "Ultimate Weapon": "Ultima Weapon"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: omg, okay thank you. little things like that just slip right past

Answer (score 1):

Each "game" should be separated by a comma.

Try -

```
var games = [
{
    "title" : "Mass Effect",
    "genre" : "Third-Person Shooter",
    "date" : "March 6, 2012",
    "character" : "Shepard",
    "weapon" : [
        {
         "Pistol" : "Kessler",
         "Assault Rifle" : "Lancer",
         "Shotgun" : "Sokolov",
         "Sniper Rifle" : "Titan"
        }
    ],  
},
{ //this bracket here is where it is telling me my syntax is wrong
    "title" : "Resident Evil",
    "genre" : "Survival Horror",
    "date" : "March 22, 1996",
    "character" : "Chris Redfield",
    "weapon" : [
        {
         "Handgun" : "Nine-Oh-Nine",
         "Assault Rifle" : "Bear Commander",
         "Shotgun" : "Triple Shot",
         "Rifle" : "Anti-Matter Rifle"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "title" : "Halo",
    "genre" : "First-Person Shooter",
    "date" : "November 15, 2001",
    "character" : " Master Chief",
    "weapon" : [
        {
         "Pistol" : "M6D Personal Defense Weapon",
         "Assault Rifle" : "MA5B Individual Combat Weapon",
         "Shotgun" : "Oathsworn",
         "Rifle" : "BR85 Heavy Barrel Service Rifle"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "title" : "Final Fantasy 7",
    "genre" : "Role-Playing Game",
    "date" : "January 31, 1997",
    "character" : "Cloud Strife",
    "weapon" :  [
        {
         "Two-Handed Sword" : "Buster Sword",
         "Katana" : "Murasame",
         "Blunt Weapon" : "Nail Bar",
         "Ultimate Weapon" : "Ultima Weapon"
        }
    ]
},
...etc
];
```